# Can you convert a date to yyyy/mm/dd using sed?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a utility that outputs the software expiration date into a text file called `expiration`. The file has one line and it is below:

`node_software_expiration_date Sat Jul 6 23:59:59 2025`

I'd like to replace the text in the file to read:

`node_software_expiration_date 20250706`

I'm using sed to replace the current text. I can't edit the utility. Open to other options.

I'm running this in cron:

`./export_expiration && sed -e 's/Software Expiration/node_software_expiration_date /' > expiration`

Comment: I can't think of any straightforward way to do this with `sed`.

Comment: It would improve the question title quite a great deal if it described the _from_ syntax, not just the _to_. Converting from `mm-dd-yyyy` to `yyyy/mm/dd`, f/e, is trivial.

Comment: It's beyond the capabilities of `sed` and probably even `awk`. I think you're into script/app code territory - try python?

Comment: @Bohemian this would be trivial in awk.

Comment: @ed I wouldn't call that trivial.

Comment: `date --date=$(./export_expiration | sed 's/Software Expiration//') +%Y%m%d` or something similar should do the trick.  You just need to separate the date from whatever other text it appears in and `date --date` can parse it.

Comment: @ChrisDodd looks promising. post an answer

Comment: @Bohemian really? it's the common, idiomatic approach for mapping 3 letter month names to numbers and then a printf to pad with zeros.

Comment: When you say "using sed" in the title -- do you _really_ mean "using sed", as in any answer using awk, or native bash, or anything not sed would be rejected? (If you just meant "using UNIX tools", _say that_ instead).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `date --date=STRING` to parse pretty much any free-form date string (it accepts many different syntaxes, so is pretty robust), and then `+FMT` to output whatever format you want.  The main difficultly with your example is replacing the file in place.  Something like:

```
read prefix date < expiration
echo $prefix $(date --date="$date" +%Y%m%d) > expiration
```

should do the trick in a shell script.  Note that if the input date string includes a time close to midnight in some other timezone, this may end up adjusting the day by one, which might actually be what you want.

Comment: It's likely that by using all upper case for your variable names you'll clash with some environment variables, especially `PREFIX`. That's why you should never use all upper case for non-environment variables see [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization). Also see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes - quotes are something to remove when you need to, not something to add when you need to. You're also missing the `-r` that should be present on all `read`s by default.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s %04d%02d%02d\n", $1, $6, (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$3)+2)/3, $4}' file
node_software_expiration_date 20250706
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -i "s/\([^ ]* \)\(.*\)/echo \1\$(date -d '\2' +'%Y%m%d')/e" input_file
$ cat input_file
node_software_expiration_date 20250706
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/$/\nJan01Feb02Mar03Apr04May05Jun06Jul07Aug08Sep09Oct10Nov11Dec12/
        s/ (. ..:..:.. )/ 0\1/
        s/... (...) (..) ..:..:.. (....)\n.*\1(..).*/\3\4\2/' file
```

Append a lookup table.

Cater for the first nine days of a month.

Pattern match, forming the result in the desired format.

Comment: Brilliant (as usual)!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{n=$1; $1=""; printf "%s ",n; print |"date -d \"" $0 "\" +%Y%m%d"} file
node_software_expiration_date 20250706
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following simple if somewhat long GNU `sed` solution, let `file.txt` content be
node_software_expiration_date Sat Jul 6 23:59:59 2025
then

```
sed -e 's/ \([0-9]\) / 0\1 /g' -e 's/\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)$/\5 \2 \3/' -e 's/ Jan /01/' -e 's/ Feb /02/' -e 's/ Mar /03/' -e 's/ Apr /04/' -e 's/ May /05/' -e 's/ Jun /06/' -e 's/ Jul /07/' -e 's/ Aug /08/' -e 's/ Sep /09/' -e 's/ Oct /10/' -e 's/ Nov /11/' -e 's/ Dec /12/' file.txt
```

gives output

```
node_software_expiration_date 20250706
```

Explanation: firstly pad single digit (digit surrounded with spaces) using 0 to width of 2. Then extract and change order of fields to that of desired format: that is year, month, day. Finally replace callsign of month and surrounding spaces with zero-padded number.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.2.2)*